# How to check for duplicate records when submitting form and return error response message to front-end

Tags: angular, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring-boot back-end restful service that serves an Angular client. When I submit user-group data with unique user-group codes from a form on the front-end, I need to add a validation check, that if a user-group code record exists such that it doesn't store duplicates in the database table. Currently, my form submits duplicate records for these user-group codes.

This is what I have done so far:
Controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/usergroups/assignrights")
public ResponseEntity<?> addUserGroup(@Validated @RequestBody 
    UserGroup userGroup) {
    userGroup = userGroupService.addGroup(userGroup);

    if (userGroup == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new 
    CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 203, false, "failed to save user 
    groups"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(new 
    CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 201, true, "data added successfully"),
            HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

service class:

```
public UserGroup addGroup(UserGroup userGroup) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupRepositories.save(userGroup);
}
```

I expect that when submitting the form, and a similar record exists,it informs user on the front-end that the user-group code exists. What is the proper way to implement this check? Thanks

Comment: As far as I understood, You wanna check db if the data exists or not? by id or what? @codeslayer

Comment: Yes, I want to check if the group code data exists, by ID, which is the unique field.

Comment: You can try to check it in your DTO class by annotating it. I meant using annotations @codeslayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently used validator for my DTO class to achieve annotation like validation such as @NotNull or @NotBlank

> Interface that your service implements

```
interface FieldValueExists{
    @Throws(UnsupportedOperationException::class)
    fun fieldValueExists(value: Any, fieldName: String): Boolean
}
```

> Annotate your ID field with the below code

```
@Unique(message = "data already exists", fieldName = "userGroupID", service UserGroupService::class, serviceQualifier = "userGroupService")
```

> Creating @Unique annotation

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.FIELD, 
AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [UniqueValidator::class])
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class Unique(
    val message: String = "{unique.value.violation}",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = [],
    val service: KClass<out FieldValueExists>,
    val serviceQualifier: String = "",
    val fieldName: String
)
```

> Creating actual validator class

```
class UniqueValidator : ConstraintValidator<Unique, Any> {
@Autowired
private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext? = null

private var service: FieldValueExists? = null
private var fieldName: String? = null

override fun initialize(unique: Unique?) {
    val clazz = unique!!.service
    this.fieldName = unique.fieldName
    val serviceQualifier = unique.serviceQualifier

    if (serviceQualifier != "") {
        this.service = this.applicationContext!!.getBean(serviceQualifier, clazz) as FieldValueExists?
    } else {
        this.service = this.applicationContext!!.getBean(clazz)
    }
}

override fun isValid(o: Any, constraintValidatorContext: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean {
    return !this.service!!.fieldValueExists(o, this.fieldName!!)
}
}
```

> And in your service class implement fieldValueExists() function and add following code and ur logic

```
 override fun fieldValueExists(value: Any, fieldName: String): Boolean {

//user groupd id should match above fieldName
    if (fieldName != "userGroupID") { 
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Field name not supported")
    }

    return groupRepositories.existsById(value as Long)
}
```

More info can be found from this link : [Reference](https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/hibernate/unique-field-validation-using-hibernate-spring)

Answer (score 0):

It depends if this will happen often or not.

Generally said you should add a unique constraint to the database. If you have this constraint you will get a `DataAccessException` (most likely a `DuplicateKeyException`) from Spring Data that you then can transform into an appropriate error message to send back to client.

If it happens very often you should add a REST endpoint where you can check existing codes with a query.

Comment: So my current implementation only needs a unique constraint to be added to DB? No further modification needed on my code?

Comment: Yes and you have to "transform into an appropriate error message to send back to client"